# Cant adjust z-index on iframed form as it stops working

Tags: html, css, iframe, position

The problem I am having is on an iframed form on my webpage where that I can't push the iframe back using `z-index` because it makes the form "un-clickable" in Chrome and Firefox.

The reason I want to push it back is because I have a fixed header on my page and when I scroll down to my iframed form the header appears under the iframe.

My header is `position:fixed` and `z-index:9999` isn't working on it.

Is there another way around it?

Here a JSFiddle of my code:[http://jsfiddle.net/G7Kc4/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Kc4/)

It seems to work how I want it to on JSFiddle

---

Or, on the flip side, If it's possible to make the iframe "clickable" in Chrome and FF after it has been pushed back using `z-index` would work just as good.

Comment: seems to work fine for me, Header is above form only http://fiddle.jshell.net/G7Kc4/show/

Comment: Yea, I noticed that it works fine in JSFiddle so maybe its my markup